# jQuery preventDefault not working correctly on iOS 9

Tags: jquery, ios, preventdefault

I am using jQuery to fade in a search box in a fixed header like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    jQuery(document).ready(function()
        {
            jQuery(".search_button").click(function()
                {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    jQuery(".h_search").fadeIn("fast");
                    jQuery( "#search" ).focus();
                }); 
   });
</script>
```

I am using preventDefault to stop the page jumping to the top when the link is clicked, it works correctly on an iPhone 4 with iOS 7 but on an iPhone 4s and iPad mini with 9 it doesnt work and the content still jumps.

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the event into the callback.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".search_button").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            jQuery(".h_search").fadeIn("fast");
            jQuery("#search").focus();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: On a side note... You dont need to invoke jQuery with jQuery() every time, you can use the $() shortcut.