# JQuery classes, such as toggleClass and dataTables, does not work on iOS 9, how to activate?

Tags: jquery, ios, ios9

Below example snippet works fine on desktop browsers and iOS 12 (Firefox and Safari), but I cannot get any JQuery functionality to work (including dataTables) on a bit older iOS (iOS 9.3.5).

I have followed the suggestion on [jQuery preventDefault not working correctly on iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322597/jquery-preventdefault-not-working-correctly-on-ios-9) by inserting `.click((event)` but no change.

Any suggestion what I am doing wrong here and how I can "activate" jQuery on iOS 9?

JavaScript is activated within settings>Safari>advanced and I have tried with JQuery 2.1.4 and 3.3.1

```js
$(function() {
  'use strict';

  $('.theme-helper-toggler').click(() => {
    $('.theme-helper').toggleClass('theme-helper-opened');
  });
});
```

```css
.clickable-div {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="theme-helper-toggler clickable-div" onclick="">
  <div class="theme-helper-spinner text-white" style="background-color: #C76708;">
    <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-thin-left"></i>
    <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-thin-right"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's possible the arrow function is the problem, but that would depend on which browser you're using on the device.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have now tried to remove arrows (and checked between .click(() and .click((event) ) I have tried Firfox and Safari and it is still not working. Is there a test case I could copy and paste in order trying to isolate the problem?